# Images not rendering on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, image, react-hooks

I have a data.js file that I have stored an image and link to a website in an array of objects.

```
export const projects = [

{
    id: 1,
    img: require("./img/ticktac.png"),
    link: "https://goatstash.github.io/tictactoby/",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    img: require("./img/minyl1.png"),
    link: "https://frozen-chamber-83680.herokuapp.com/",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    img: require("./img/nets.png"),
    link: "https://netzforall.herokuapp.com/",
  },
];
```

I am then importing them into my Projects.js component which isn't rendering anything at the moment. Previously it was rendering a broken image when on the data.js file i had the object set like this (or something very similar it may have been "../../img/ticktac.png" for example but it would render a broken image:

```
export const projects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: "./img/ticktac.png",
    link: "https://goatstash.github.io/tictactoby/",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    img: "./img/minyl1.png",
    link: "https://frozen-chamber-83680.herokuapp.com/",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    img: "./img/nets.png",
    link: "https://netzforall.herokuapp.com/",
  },
];
```

My Project.js component looks like this:

```
 import "./projects.css";
    import { projects } from "../../data";
    
    const Projects = ({ img, link }) => {
      return (
        <div className="p">
          <div className="p-browser">
            <div className="p-circle"></div>
            <div className="p-circle"></div>
            <div className="p-circle"></div>
          </div>
          <a href={link} target="_blank">
            <img src={img} alt="" className="p-img" />
          </a>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Projects;

and from there it goes to my programlist.js component:
import "./projectlist.css";
import Projects from "../projects/Projects";
import { projects } from "../../data";

const ProjectList = () => {
  return (
    <div className="pl">
      <div className="pl-texts">
        <h1 className="pl-title">Projects</h1>
        <p className="pl-description">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum sunt ad
          vitae. Quo maxime quos odit? Fuga omnis suscipit numquam adipisci unde
          aliquid vel deleniti ex eos excepturi. Atque, nostrum.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="pl-list">
        {projects.map((item) => {
          <Projects key={item.id} img={item.img} link={item.link} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectList;
```

Currently nothing is rendering on my page which I would really appreciate some help with.
I think maybe I should be targeting the projects variable as projects[0] but i was rendering before hand when I didn't change the img value to require("./img/ticktac.png").

Comment: What error do you get, probally a 404, so the path to your images is not correct.

Comment: no error just doesn't render anything

Answer (score -1):

Try to use your `absolute path`, something like

```
<Projects key={item.id} img={`${process.env.basePath}${item.img}`} link={item.link} />;
```

You are trying to load `object` instead of `url` needed for `<img />` tag
Try to hardcode link for your test, something like

```
<Projects key={item.id} img={`http://localhost:3000${item.img}`} link={item.link} />;
```

P.S. Of course, you should set up your base url.